# JFrame color change

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a JFrame that appears at the end of a timer. The code below pops up the frame and a sound. The color of the frame is set from a menu and then it's given to the frame. I need the frame to alternate between default color and the color i select in the menu. Thanks in advance

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
      {
        public void run()
        {
            JFrame frame= new JFrame(); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(600, 400);
            frame.setLocation(200, 200);
            frame.setTitle("ALARM");
            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(GUI.this.timerPanel.colorButton.getBackground());  // *This is the source for the color i select in the menu* 
            JLabel welcome = new JLabel("",SwingConstants.CENTER);
            welcome.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 48));
            welcome.setText("ALARM ALARM ALARM");
            frame.add(welcome);
            new SoundEngine().playSound();





        }
      })

        .start();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swing** isn't `Thread` friendly, try learning about `SwingUtility.InvokeLater`.

To change `Color` use `JFrame.setBackGround(color)`.

Now how will you toggle?

For me the best way is to create a `Class`, named `Util`.

```
public class Util{
     private static int ser=0;
     private static Color[] backColor=new Color[]{Color.red,Color.green,Color.white};
     public static void setBC(JFrame frame){
         frame.setBackGround(backColor[ser++%backColor.lenght]);
}
```

Now on your *extended* `JFrame` class or section just call `Util.setBC(frame)` .

It changes between these three color, you can add more or even remove soem as you wish.